# The cloned project I have no permission to change it

Tags: git, permissions, project

I use the `sudo git pull`(use `git pull` do not have permission) the project from other computer in my office, but  when I use PyCharm open the project, I have no permission to change the files, only has the read permission.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

How can I possess the permission to alter these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would not need sudo to pull.

But if you do and have access to sudo, then a `sudo chown -R youruser:yourgroup yourRepo/` should be enough to give you the right to modify the files after a pull.

Or, as [mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17015/7490):

```
cd dir_of_repo
sudo chown -R ${LOGNAME} $(pwd)
sudo chmod -R u+rwX $(pwd)
```